# Angular 14: Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Tags: angular

So on my form I have:

```
<form [formGroup]="User" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
....
....
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit"  color="primary" [disabled]="!User.valid">Sign-up</button>
    <p>Already have an account?</p><button mat-raised-button  type="button" color="secondary" routerLink="/login">Log in</button>
</form>
```

and in my code behind:

```
async onSubmit() {
     this.authService.signUp(this.User.value);
}
```

I have tried adding `$event` as a parameter to the onSubmit, then adding `e.preventDefault()` in the code behind, but I still get the  above error. I've also tried removing the `async` from my `onSubmit`, still made no difference. I then removed the `(ngSubmit)` from the form and made it a click on the button, but still get the error.

[image]

The error occurs as soon as I select the form from my main form.

interestingly, if I remove `(ngSubmit)..` from my form element change my button type from `submit` to `button` and introduce a click event on the button and change the method name being called. I still receive the same error.

Comment: Which is the error? could you add some information of it?

Comment: try to remove the async keyword from the onSubmit() method

Comment: @MoufeedJuboqji removing async keyword made no difference

Comment: Doh! the error was in relation to where I was coming from I had forgotton to put the button types on the parent form